# NSDateFormatter not converting string to date correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, timestamp, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Instead of giving output `2017-10-01 23:00:00 +0000`, the date formatter below gives `2016-12-25 23:00:00 +0000`.

```
// Convert string to date object
NSString *inputString = @"10-01-2017";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-YYYY"];
NSDate *outputDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:inputString];
NSLog(@"inputString={%@} outputDate={%@}",inputString, outputDate.description);
```

Output:

```
inputString={10-01-2017} outputDate={2016-12-25 23:00:00 +0000}
```

Comment: `YYYY` vs `yyyy`?. Check there: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: @Larme Changing to `yyyy` solved my problem.